# AEM forms/ Adobe Form submission failure on publish instance. Error code: AEM-AF-901-004

Tags: aem, adobe-form

AEM version/SP: **6.5.11**

AEM forms add-on package: **adobe-aemfd-linux-pkg-6.0.566-NPR-37836-B0001.zip**

I've created an AEM form on author instance. The form submission is working in author instance. When I publish the form from the console & test it in publish instance, the form submission is failing.
Types of submit action tested:

1. No action configured
2. Forms Portal Submit action
3. Send PDF via email
4. Send email
5. Submit to Rest endpoint
6. Use asynchronous submission - i) Redirect to URL ii) Show message

To summarize, I've tested multiple variations of form submit actions. But none of the scenario is working.

Alert message[Screenshot attached]:

**[AF] [AEM-AF-901-004]: Encountered an internal error while submitting the form.**

The difference that I observe in author-submission & publish-submission is that:
/aem-forms-01/jcr:content/guideContainer.af.**internalsubmit.jsp**

This above mentioned request is failing in publish instance.
In publish instance the request attributes are:

- the error code I see is ***Status Code: 500 Server Error***
- the request header for content type is - ***Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8***
  whereas, in author instance the request header shows content-type as - application/json [screenshot attached].

From the error logs I understand that

- In author instance the form data is submitted as application json, as expected, and so it works.
- In publish instance the form data is submitted as plain text format and the data is expected to be in json format hence get following error:

*com.adobe.aemds.guide.internal.impl.servlet.GuideInternalSubmitServlet Expected a ':' after a key at character 7 of {"guideState":{"guideDom":* [...error trace continued]

Kindly provide suggestions to resolve this issue in AEM publish instance

Please refer the following screenshots.

[image: Form creation]

[image: AEM form submit error - publish]

[image: AEM form submit content-type - publish]

[image: AEM form submit content-type - author]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dispatcher at front, add the following rule to allow those URLs to be served:

```
/0229 { /type "allow" /method "POST" /path "/content/forms/af/[A-Za-z0-9-]*/[A-Za-z0-9-]*/jcr:content/guideContainer*" /extension '(jsp)'}  # allow POSTs to submit AEM Forms under /content
```

Review configurations at https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/forms/install-aem-forms/configure-aem-forms/configure-adaptive-forms-cache.html?lang=en